# Splitting a deck of cards, and returning the results as if they were shuffled once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with a deck of cards, numbered 01-52. I could return the top and bottom cards, as if I held each side of the union's select query in my left and right hands by doing a:

```
select top 26 * from DeckOfCards order by CardNumber desc
union all
select top 26 * from DeckOfCards order by CardNumber asc
```

It would be an even split.

But how could I have SQL Server intertwine the results returned, as if I had taken both portions of that union, one half in my left hand, and the other in my right, and shuffled them once like a deck of cards?

IE:
CardNumber 52, followed by 1, in the following sequence:
52, 1, 51, 2, 50, 3, 49, 4, etc...

This is not a homework question, just one of those things that passes through my mind when trying to get some shut eye. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little math can help achieving this

```
SELECT CardNumber
FROM   DeckOfCards 
ORDER BY (1 - CAST(CardNumber / 27 as bit)) * (CardNumber* 2)
       + (CAST(CardNumber/ 27 as bit)) * (1 + (52 - CardNumber) * 2)
```

`CAST(CardNumber / 27 as bit)` returns 0 for the card number below 27 and 1 for the number above 26, using this it's possible to create a different order for the two different block:

- `(1 - CAST(CardNumber / 27 as bit)) * (CardNumber* 2)` put the first 26 card in the even position, as the first member will be 1 for those card and 0 for the other
- `(CAST(CardNumber/ 27 as bit)) * (1 + (52 - CardNumber) * 2)` will put the second 26 card in the odd position, e.g. `(1 + (52 - CardNumber) * 2)` will return odd values in descending order

<kbd>[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/211b3/2)</kbd> with the order formula as a second column to see how it works

Comment: Excellent answer, and nice trick with the order by.

Comment: FYI the extra join is intentional, to shuffle only ids (not any additional attributes). The second solution is indeed semantically similar, though it does not avoid a size-of-data sort, which was my stated aim. There are all sorts (ha!) of little issues like `53 - CardNumber` not being an order-preserving function, but I don't suppose anyone except me will care about that. With an input of 52 rows, you're probably right not to care; however, on larger tasks, avoiding sorts by properly considering order preservation can be important.

Comment: @PaulWhite I never said that it was better or that the `JOIN` was wrong, I only pointed out the difference between the two, also thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to provide an alternative solution (using the sample data in [Serpiton's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66128/1192) - thanks!) that avoids sorts. This *ought* to be possible using `ROW_NUMBER`, but the query optimizer doesn't currently recognize its projection as unique. So:

```
DECLARE @TopHalf AS TABLE 
(
    id integer IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CardID integer NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @BottomHalf AS TABLE 
(
    id integer IDENTITY (0,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CardID integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT TOP (26) @TopHalf (CardID)
SELECT D.id
FROM dbo.deck AS D
ORDER BY D.id ASC;

INSERT TOP (26) @BottomHalf (CardID)
SELECT D.id
FROM dbo.deck AS D
ORDER BY D.id DESC;

SELECT 
    D.id,
    D.[card]
FROM
(
    SELECT id, CardID FROM @TopHalf AS TH
    UNION
    SELECT id, CardID FROM @BottomHalf AS BH
) AS Shuffled
JOIN dbo.deck AS D
    ON D.id = Shuffled.CardID
ORDER BY 
    Shuffled.id, 
    Shuffled.CardID;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49f44/2)**

Output:

[image: Output]

Execution plans:

[image: Execution plans]

Answer (score 0):

The key is to have an `ORDER BY` that can work with the data from both sets. I used `ROW_NUMBER` to get a bit more general solution, but it would be possible to avoid the sorts by doing direct math on the card numbers.

```
WITH DeckOfCards (CardNumber) AS (
    SELECT TOP 52
        number
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P' AND number > 0
),
Ranks AS (
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CardNumber ASC) AscOrder
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CardNumber DESC) DescOrder
    FROM
        DeckOfCards
)
SELECT
    CardNumber
FROM
    Ranks
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            MAX(n) AS Ranking
            , CASE WHEN DescOrder > AscOrder THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DeckHalf
        FROM (VALUES (AscOrder), (DescOrder)) AS T(n)
    ) A
ORDER BY
A.Ranking DESC, A.DeckHalf
```